# Invalid object name after aliasing a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I run the following query

```
select distinct A.movieID, A.avgStars from 
(select mID as movieID, avg(stars) as avgStars
from Rating
group by mID) A
where  A.avgStars <= all(select A.avgStars from A);
```

I get the error "Invalid object name 'A'."

Do you know why I'm getting this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can't reference an alias from a subquery at the same scope. You can do this with a CTE, though; perhaps you meant:

```
;WITH Avgs AS
(
  select mID as movieID, avg(stars) as avgStars
  from Rating group by mID
)
SELECT movieID, avgStars FROM Avgs
WHERE avgStars <= ALL (SELECT AvgStars FROM Avgs);
```

You shouldn't need `DISTINCT` there, either.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers have already identified the problem and how to solve it.

Here is another way, that simplifies the query further:

```
select top (1) with ties
    mID as movieID, avg(stars) as avgStars
from Rating 
group by mID
order by avgStars ;
```

According to the condition you were trying to apply:

```
A.avgStars <= all(select A.avgStars from A)
```

your query is supposed to return only the entries with the lowest average. The same logic can be expressed in a simpler way with `top (1) with ties` + `order by`, as shown above.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to reference the alias in your `from` statement in a new subquery.

You could do something like that with a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) though.

```
;with a as (
select mID as movieID, avg(stars) as avgStars
  from Rating
  group by mID
)

select distinct A.movieID, A.avgStars 
from a
where  A.avgStars <= all(select A.avgStars from A);
```

Answer (score 4):

The is failing because your Where clause. The `all(select A.avgStars from A)` cannot see the "A" table aliased above in this context. It thinks you're trying to link to a table named A.

Answer (score -2):

Try executing with **AS**

```
select distinct A.movieID, A.avgStars from 
(select mID as movieID, avg(stars) as avgStars
from Rating
group by mID) AS A
where  A.avgStars <= all(select A.avgStars from A);
```